# Android Http response shows after second click only

Tags: android, android-fragments, get, httprequest

I am trying to make a **HTTP GET** when I click on the navigation drawer menu, it call a fragment and my HTTP code is in that fragment. When I click it first it not shows the response data(but in logcat I can see the HTTP get is send and received) but when I click to an other menu in the navigation drawer, and try the original again(it makes an other HTTP request) it shows what I want. What can be the problem?

```
public class FragmentInternet extends android.app.Fragment {

private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";

private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

private String cookies;
private String textout;
private TextView t;

public FragmentInternet() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static FragmentInternet newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    FragmentInternet fragment = new FragmentInternet();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

    new PostClass(getContext()).execute();
    cookies = MainStatusActivity.cookietoheader;

}

class PostClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private final Context context;


    public PostClass(Context c){

        this.context = c;
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://example.json");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Request URI", "/example.json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Request Version", "HTTP/1.1");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "example.com");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json, text/javascript, */*");
            connection.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");
            connection.setRequestProperty("USER-AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Referer","http://speedport.ip/html/content/internet/connection.html?lang=en");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT-LANGUAGE", "hu-HU,hu;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);

            String responseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("Request URL " + url);
            output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator")  + "Response Code " + responseCode);
            output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator")  + "Response message " + responseMessage);
            output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Type " + "GET");
            output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Cookie " + cookies);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            StringBuilder responseOutput = new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println("output===============" + br);
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
                responseOutput.append(line);
            }
            br.close();

            output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Response " + System.getProperty("line.separator") + System.getProperty("line.separator") + responseOutput.toString());
            textout = responseOutput.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
        t.setText(textout);
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_internet, container,false);
    t = (TextView) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.showOutput);
    t.setText(textout);
    return myInflatedView;
}

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

EDIT: Working code Thanks to carthurs:

```
public class FragmentInternet extends android.app.Fragment {
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private String cookies;
private String textout;
private TextView t;

public FragmentInternet() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
public static FragmentInternet newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    FragmentInternet fragment = new FragmentInternet();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
    cookies = MainStatusActivity.cookietoheader;
}
class PostClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private final Context context;
    public PostClass(Context c){
        this.context = c;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://examlpe.json");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Request URI", "/example.json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Request Version", "HTTP/1.1");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "example.com");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json, text/javascript, */*");
            connection.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");
            connection.setRequestProperty("USER-AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Referer","http://speedport.ip/html/content/internet/connection.html?lang=en");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT-LANGUAGE", "hu-HU,hu;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);

            String responseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("Request URL " + url);
            output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator")  + "Response Code " + responseCode);
            output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator")  + "Response message " + responseMessage);
            output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Type " + "GET");
            output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Cookie " + cookies);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            StringBuilder responseOutput = new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println("output===============" + br);
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
                responseOutput.append(line);
            }
            br.close();

            output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Response " + System.getProperty("line.separator") + System.getProperty("line.separator") + responseOutput.toString());
            textout = output.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void ignored) {
        t.setText(textout);
    }
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_internet, container,false);
    t = (TextView) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.showOutput);
    t.setText(textout);
    new PostClass(getContext()).execute();
    return myInflatedView;
}
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

Comment: I notice that you execute your `PostClass` in `onCreate()`, but don't assign `t` until `onCreateView()` (which is called after `onCreate()` - look up the Fragment Lifecycle). Is something crashing?

Comment: Well i needed to delete OnAttack(), because if it was in it crashed :(
When the t is in the oncreate it not shows anything at all

Comment: That sounds like a different problem (were you definitely calling `super.onAttach()` within your `onAttach()`? ). Why not move your PostClass into `onCreateView()`, after the line where you assign `t`?

Comment: If i put it like this it also the same :(


@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_internet, container,false);
        t = (TextView) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.showOutput);
        new PostClass(getContext()).execute();
        t.setText(textout);

        return myInflatedView;
    }

Comment: Hmm. Is your onPostExecute actually called (put `Log.d("in onPostExecute", "called!");` in there to see). It may not be called due to the Void return type you're setting in `AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>`

Comment: 03-13 17:04:22.331 23141-23141/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
03-13 17:04:23.445 23141-23141/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 E/in onPostExecute: called!
03-13 17:04:23.480 23141-23141/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
03-13 17:04:25.173 23141-23680/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 I/System.out: Sending 'POST' request to URL : http://speedport.ip/data/INetIP.json
03-13 17:04:25.174 23141-23680/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 
This is the logcat.
How should i set the AsyncTask?

Comment: `03-13 17:04:23.445 23141-23141/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 E/in onPostExecute: called!`

`03-13 17:04:25.173 23141-23680/com.dxir1p.molnardk.telekom0224 I/System.out: Sending 'POST' request to URL : speedport.ip/data/INetIP.json`

did you press the button twice, or is your POST request really being sent /after/ `onPostExecute`, as the timestemps suggest?

The parameter type passed to `onPostExecute` should match the type Z in `AsyncTask<X,Y,Z>`, and should be the return type of `doInBackground`.

Try changing `onPostExecute()` to `onPostExecute(Void ignored)`

Comment: onPostExecute(Void ignored) It works ! :D Thank you very much ^^

Comment: HTH! Feel free to upvote the more helpful comments ;)

Comment: I know it is an od question but how i can upvote your answer? :)

Comment: Ah you can't - you need a reputation of 15 to upvote a comment apparently. I've re-written my response as an answer below, which you can accept (by clicking the tick next to it) if you think it's a good summary of how to fix your problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can always accept an answer - the tick, not the up-arrow. See here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Ah thanks :D it is worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `onPostExecute()` is not being called correctly because its signature does not match with what your `AsyncTask` expects.

When you create `AsyncTask<X,Y,Z>`, you are stating that the type `Z` will be the return-type of `protected Z doInBackground()` and also that it will be the argument of `onPostExecute(Z myZ)`. The purpose of this is to allow passing of a result of the background computation to `onPostExecute`.

In your case, you've stated that your result is a `Void`, so you need to change your
`onPostExecute()`
to
`onPostExecute(Void ignored)`
so that the signature matches, allowing it to be called correctly.